# Crystals and Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would really appreciate some clarification on group theory in relation to crystallography. I know there has been lots of research and studies on this topic, but specifically I am looking at crystals. I know they are a group, but am curious of these other questions:

- What is the binary operation? What are the elements and how does it work?
  -Can crystals be expanded to a greater structure? (i.e can a monoid become a group, a group a ring, etc)
  -What substructures can you find?

Comment: Basically the group is the group of symmetries of a crystal, rotations, reflections and translations. When we say symmetry we mean a transformation which leave the crystal invariant. The binary operation is composition.

Comment: Group of symmetries can be studied for anything, crystals are just cases in which the symmetries are specially interesting due to their discreteness and simplicity. Also they are interesting due to physical reasons. Also there are some combinatorical aspect to them, things like Coxeter and Reflection groups.

Comment: Crystals aren't an algebraic object, but their "building blocks" (I don't know chemistry; atoms, molecules?) can be associated with points in a vector space with a restricted scalar multiplication. See [space groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group) and [(point) lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) for some relevant things.

Comment: [wiki/Lattice_(group)#Symmetry_considerations_and_examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)#Symmetry_considerations_and_examples)

Answer (score 2):

Crystals are not properly groups, but their groups of symmetries, know as the Crystalographic groups or (in two dimensions) [Wallpaper groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group), are very important. The binary operation is naturally the composition of symmetries, as in every group of symmetries. These groups were classified long time ago ([1891](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evgraf_Fedorov)), though you may want to look at Conway's classification known as the [Magic Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold_notation).

If you want to consider crystals as in a more general framework, you could take a look at [quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal). Quasicrystals' 'symmetries' (or quasi-symmetries) are [sometimes](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.0080.pdf) studied as **partial isometries** (symmetries defined on subsets) which form a groupoid (pseudo-group) rather than a group.